# turn on anti aliasing in d3d9?

Tags: directx, game-engine, direct3d, multisampling

I'm trying to turn on anti aliasing in my project. first look the d3d9 interface:

```
HRESULT CreateRenderTarget(
  [in]           UINT Width,
  [in]           UINT Height,
  [in]           D3DFORMAT Format,
  [in]           D3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE MultiSample,
  [in]           DWORD MultisampleQuality,
  [in]           BOOL Lockable,
  [out, retval]  IDirect3DSurface9 **ppSurface,
  [in]           HANDLE *pSharedHandle
);

typedef enum D3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE {
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE           = 0,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE    = 1,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES      = 2,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_3_SAMPLES      = 3,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_4_SAMPLES      = 4,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_5_SAMPLES      = 5,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_6_SAMPLES      = 6,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_7_SAMPLES      = 7,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_8_SAMPLES      = 8,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_9_SAMPLES      = 9,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_10_SAMPLES     = 10,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_11_SAMPLES     = 11,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_12_SAMPLES     = 12,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_13_SAMPLES     = 13,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_14_SAMPLES     = 14,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_15_SAMPLES     = 15,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_16_SAMPLES     = 16,
  D3DMULTISAMPLE_FORCE_DWORD    = 0xffffffff 
} D3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE, *LPD3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE;
```

I am not sure how to give the parameter `MultiSample` and `MultisampleQuality`. what is the difference between `non-maskable multisampling` and `maskable`? 
What does 2x anti-aliasing map to? 
what does 4x anti-aliasing map to? 
does D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES + 2q == D3DMULTISAMPLE_4_SAMPLES + 1q?

Answer (score 2):

`MultisampleQuality` is only available if you take `D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE` as multisampletype ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

`D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE` enables only antialiasing-support (thats what you look for) and the quality is determined by the `MultisampleQuality`-Parameter, where 1 => 2xAA and 2 => 4xAA.

If you use a type other then `D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE`, e.g. 'D3DMULTISAMPLE_2_SAMPLES' you enable additionaly to the antialising-support a writing mask, which you can set by the renderstate `D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEMASK` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). This enables you to render to a specific set of samples of your multisampled rendertarget. Finally all samples are averaged and presented. I assume that this setting isn't the right for your problem.